# Web GUI for python scripts

Tags: python, user-interface, web, freebsd

Lets say I have some scripts that I run on FreeBSD 11 (python or SH), they take some arguments, etc and return some metrics or console output messages, is it possible to write a Web GUI to provide a front-end for those scripts? Some way that it would let the user input the arguments (or pick from dropdown boxes) and display the output of the scripts.

I was reading around and cant find where to start. I would like the GUI to be visually appealing, so it can also show a Dashboard with gauges, for CPU, HDD and RAM.

I guess I need some sort of Web Server on the FreeBSD machine, and perhaps to create some site using some widgets, etc.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Your application itself can be the webserver so that you don't need an external server such as apache. You can use a microframework like flask, bottle, cherrypy, web.py, etc.

Comment: Thats great info!, which of those would be more future-proof, in terms of compatibility with browsers, functionality and ability to extend with more screens, widgets, dashboards, etc?

Comment: None of what you said makes sense. Browser compatibility, screens, widgets, dashboards are a function of the html that you write and have virtually nothing to do with the underlying server.

Comment: Yes, no sense,, thats why I was asking. Maybe my question needs to be steered on the right direction. I mentioned a technical component (ability to run python/SH scripts from a Web GUI), perhaps that can be done with some tool, framework or language. I also mentioned a component of usability and presentation (Dashboards, widgets, etc), perhaps that needs to be done some other way, with HTML, who knows,  perhaps a good advise would be "yes, the funtionality can be achieve with XXXXX and YYYYY or ZZZZZ, and the presentation part would need to be done with DDDDDD, or EEEEE, etc etc,

Comment: and if you want both to work together, there are this KKKKKKK frameworks/languages/software, etc , that does that well, or here are some examples,, blah blah blah. ,, again,, sorry, my question doesnt make sense,, I just wanted a little direction,, or perhaps telling me "no, none of that is possible"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Django with Apache and MySQL. This [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-a-django-site-with-apache-mod_wsgi-and-mysql-on-freebsd-10-1) might help.

Comment: Thanks Jason,, I read a bit about Django, and from architectural point I like the idea of having a DB storing everything that the users input or what the scripts return, for historical purposes.

Comment: Thanks Jason,, I read a bit about Django, and from architectural point I like the idea of having a DB storing everything that the users input or what the scripts return, for historical purposes. Do you know any sites or sample application where I could see a mock-up or something functional that gives me an idea of the possibilities of Django? specially in visual terms. Is it possible to have some dynamic dashboards with Django? for example that change gauges as CPU or Memory utilization changes?